# Boost wserialization and linking issue

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I'm trying to build an .exe in Visual Studio 2017, and keep getting messages of linking error (LNK 2001), actually there are 18 of them, both with Debug or Release, x86 or x64.

I am using Boost_1_63_msvc14 from the **pre-built binary** download.

I have read the LNK 2001 page in the Microsoft-msdn website and the Boost reference. Anyway, with narrow chars it worked flawlessly. Both serialization and **w**serialization library are present.

Compiling and linking was set up as follows:

- the compiler with "Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directiories -> (The Boost dir)"
- the linker with "Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories -> (The Boost dir/lib64-msvc-14.0)" and "Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> (the library itself)"
- "Properties -> C/C++ -> All Options -> Treat WChar_t As Built in Type -> Yes(/Zc:wchar_t)"
- "Properties -> C/C++ -> All Options -> Calling Convention -> __cdecl(/Gd)"

With narrow serialization I didn't need to specify the Linker-Input->... so I tried also without doing it.

I included any useful library:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/basic_binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/basic_binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_wiarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_woarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/basic_binary_iprimitive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/basic_binary_oprimitive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/deque.hpp>
```

Examples of errors from the linker:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "protected: void __cdecl boost::archive::basic_binary_oarchive<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive>::init(void)" (?init@?$basic_binary_oarchive@Vbinary_woarchive@archive@boost@@@archive@boost@@IEAAXXZ) prog1   C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\prog1_SOLU\prog1\func.obj   1   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "protected: __cdecl boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::basic_binary_oprimitive<class boost::archive::binary_woarchive,wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >(class std::basic_streambuf<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> > &,bool)" (??0?$basic_binary_oprimitive@Vbinary_woarchive@archive@boost@@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@archive@boost@@IEAA@AEAV?$basic_streambuf@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@std@@_N@Z)  prog1   C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\prog1_SOLU\prog1\func.obj   1
```

What am I dong wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are linking to the wrong library maybe?

Comment: It's worth noting with boost that you (usually) don't need to specify the linked library manually, and that the headers contain `#pragma` statements to link the correct libraries automatically. So try clearing out the boost library references in the "Additional Dependencies" field.

Comment: I usually did as Xirema says, and leaved the Linker -> Input blank, have #pragma once on each header but still get the errors.